# mysql extension is deprecated unknown reason

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$sitename = "Site Name";

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('databasename', $link);

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue) {

    if($finder == "1") $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename");

    else $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE 

`$finder`='$findervalue'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    return $row[$rowname];
}

?>
```

Having a unknown problem i dont know why but its saying that

> Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u759655205/public_html/set.php on line 9

Line 9 :    `else $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE`$finder`='$findervalue'");`

Comment: It is saying it's deprecated because [it's deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: The error is literally telling you what the issue is. `mysql_query` is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)...

Comment: Deprecated means that it is going to be removed from PHP in the future, specifically in November of this year with the release of PHP7

Comment: [Here is an example of what happens when you continue to use `mysql_*` functions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299564/php-version-upgraded-cannot-use-few-functions) Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: In short, prepared statements are much nicer in terms of constructing a query, and they help protect against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

the MySQL module is depreciated in PHP5, instead use

- MySQLi http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- PHP::PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

MySQLi is very similar to MySql in PHP with some major changes.

If you must use MySQL you have the option of surpressing errors

from another post: [php mysql_connect Warning disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912899/php-mysql-connect-warning-disable)

```
$dblink = @mysql_connect(DBHOST_LOCAL, DBUSER, DBPASS);

if (!$dblink) 
{
    $dblink = @mysql_connect(DBHOST_REMOTE, DBUSER, DBPASS);                  
}

if (!$dblink)
{
    $message = sprintf(
        "Could not connect to local or remote database: %s",
        mysql_error()
    );
    trigger_error($message);
    return;
}
```

I advise you to use this form of error suppressing since your error is specific.

Comment: If he does that then it won't show other types of errors.

Comment: I wouldn't do this, i would update my code.