# php/mysqlconnect deprecated error: Best way to upgrade to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a lot of code for a website in php that uses deprecated mysql functions. (Sql injection protection was via real_escape_string). I am suddenly getting warnings at top of page that mysql_connect is deprecated probably because my host has upgrade their version of PHP and there is no question I have to upgrade to mysqli asap.  This is no easy task as we are talking thousands of calls.

However, althoughthe site is flashing these warnings, the majority of the calls still work, i.e. you can log in and display data-driven pages. In fact I am getting warnings  about just three functions, mysql_connect, mysql_numrows and dates.

Why would the database connection still work if mysql_connect supposedly is now totally deprecated?  As a quick fix while I undertake the job of upgrading the whole site, can anyone suggest a substitute for mysql_numrows.

Thanks for any insights or suggestions.

Comment: This can easily be Google'd.

Comment: I've already googled it.  No good answers.  I take it you don't have any suggestions other than check google?

Comment: Deprecated and removed are two different things, which is why it still works (unless the host upgraded to 7 or above)

Comment: what are you asking about a substitute for `mysql_numrows`? You're going to have to elaborate on that and post some code.

Comment: oh and `mysql_` will still work, up until (and if you're on a hosted site) they change it to a PHP version that no longer supports those functions. Again; Google'able and is on the PHP.net website. If on local, then still with the PHP version you have now. *"Best way to upgrade to mysqli"* - There is no "best" way; you just do.

Comment: I have emailed my host to inquire if they've changed something about the warning messages.  It has been deprecated for some time but my host still had older version.

Comment: so you want to suppress warnings probably; here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16912923/ while still using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: You can use `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);` temporarily while you are trying to upgrade to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). And the best recommendation that we can give is to study [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I should add, one other thing suddenly stopped working.  Images which were displayed using a library.

Comment: error reporting will tell you that ^ if paths were changed etc.

Comment: How do I turn on error reporting?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Ok. Thx.  I will try that.  I have one file called at beginning of all the others so I can just put it there.

Comment: however, use error reporting inside all `.php` files, so if one file/or more (say an included file) fails, it will show you which file(s) and on which line.

Comment: ...and to somewhat answer your question *"a substitute for mysql_numrows"*: you can use `count()` as either an aggregate MySQL function, or as a PHP function. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html and http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php and using that inside a conditional statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While this can be Googled, I want to explain the answer to the asker, and allow future readers to understand this question easily.

Deprecated code doesn't *necessarily* mean the code won't work. It indicates that it is no longer supported.

Now in theory, you can just go and put an `@` in front of the function and the error won't appear. Now I recommend you **NEVER DO THIS** in a working environment. It exists to suppress warnings, but it still means you have security weaknesses. All php functions that express `mysql_functionName()` are outdated (or deprecated). To fix this, use something along the lines of `mysqli_functionName()` instead.

Using mysqli allows you to stay up to date. Now I see you are using procedural styling. This is allowed, but it is recommended that you use **object-oriented-programming or PDO**. I personally use OOP-mysqli.

Now it should be noted that it is not a seamless transition; meaning you cannot simply just add the `i` in `mysql`. Functions such as `mysqli_connect()` are [different](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php). `mysqli_num_rows()` on the other hand should handle the same by just adding the `i` in `mysql`. Check the Mysqli Documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for more info on the transitions.

---

To be more elaborate:

**This are nearly the same:**
 `mysqli_num_rows()`

**These are different:**
`mysqli_connect()`, `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

**This is removed**
`mysql_result()` (There is no built in equivalent in `mysqli`).

I hope this answer was elaborate enough for you.

---

**EDIT:**

Based on the question asked by the asker, it is not possible to combine both `mysql` and `mysqli` together. They are different calls to the database. If you call a `mysqli_connect()`, the variable you set it to is connected to that db call. It will only recognize `mysqli`. A lot of functions in `mysqli` such as `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `mysqli_query()` require you to pass the connection of the original db call.

In conclusion, don't try to mix calls. It won't work and it has a lot of security issues and flaws.

It is my opinion that one should completely rewrite their code when the entire infrastructure changes, since it is safer to not risk any old code that might have been left behind in edits. This of course has a major flaw; being it means having to work super hard to rebuild. It is up to the user in this case depending on the size of the project.

Comment: Ok.  THx.  Got some good news. Host made upgrade for security reasons but it turns they have option for me to switch php version back so I have more time to do this.  The specifics are very helpful.

Comment: One last question.  Can these mysql and mysqli co-exist or do I have to change and debug everything before it will work correctly?  I read somewhere they use same underlying library.

Comment: @user1904273 I went back and edited the question for you.